# Not able to change Target OS version from 10.0.22000.0 to 10.0.19041

Tags: c#, .net

[Hello I am not able to change  Target OS version from 10.0.22000.0 to 10.0.19041.]

With C# .NET 7.0 and Visual Studio 2022

I should be able to change target OS versions to previous version which visual studio is not allowing

Comment: Why does it matter? v10 is Windows 10, no matter the build. There is very little difference

Comment: You removed the screenshot.